# How to specify OPENSSL system variables?

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

I am trying to include OpenSSL in a simple C++ project, compiled using CMake to create the Makefile on Windows. Every time I try to compile it, it gives me this error:

> Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY)

or

> Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)

I have the folder cloned from https://github.com/openssl/openssl, and have set environment variables for both user and system. I have also passed the following arguments on the command line:

```
-DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY="C:/Users/____/openssl/crypto" -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR="C:/Users/____/openssl" -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:/Users/____/openssl/include"
```

Here's what my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.0)
project(PasswordGen)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(PasswordGen main.cpp)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(OpenSSL::SSL)
```

What should I do to properly link in OpenSSL?

Comment: "OpenSSL root folder" means directory where OpenSSL is **installed**. Having only *sources* of OpenSSL is not sufficient.

Comment: This line hasn't run yet, but it's clearly wrong... you need to write `target_link_libraries(PasswordGen PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL)`

Comment: Forward-slashes?  For Windows paths, try using backslashes: \